# Calling a node.js script from java using ProcessBuilder in mac

Tags: java, macos, node.js, process, processbuilder

I am very much new to mac and its directory structure.

I have a node.js script on my desktop and the path to it is: `/Users/username/Desktop/webserver`

I would like to run this script(Along with an argument) within java using ProcessBuilder in Mac OSX.

In windows using Runtime, i would do something like:

```
String [] env=null;
String[]callAndArgs= {"node","server.js",argument};

Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(callAndArgs,env,
new java.io.File("Path to my server.js file"));

BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));//getting the input

BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));//getting the error

interface_name = stdInput.readLine();//reading the output
```

How can I accomplish the same in mac, as when I input the `/Users/username/Desktop/webserver` as path to my node.js script, I get an error saying

```
java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Java is platform independent. So the Mac path should work without any trouble unless the `java` process doesn't have permission to access the file.

Make sure that the permissions are fine.

Comment: But is the path precise? Cause the output reads path not found.

Comment: Check if the case is correct (Only windows allows case-insensitive paths). Also check if you have special characters. Better still execute the command `cat /path/to/myfile.extension` to see if the terminal can read it.

Comment: When I type `cat /Users/username/Desktop/serialport/listport.js` in the terminal the file opens.